# Web Application Infrastructure for continuous integration - How many servers?

Tags: testing, server, version-control, teamcity, infrastructure

We're currently a small team of 3 developers and want to move to a new set up for deploying, testing and hosting our web applications.

Our current set up is:

Version Control Server (1) - We're using SVN on this server.

Web Server (2) - Used for testing/demoing new functionality to clients.

Web Server (3) - Hosts 5 ASP.NET web applications (10k users daily)

Web Server (4) - Failover server for web applications

Database Server (5) - MS SQL Server

Database Failover Server (6) - MS SQL Server

So thats 6 servers we have in total.

The team use Visual Studio on our local machines for development and also test locally only. When a build is ready we publish from one our developer machines and FTP to the test web server before then also publishing to the live web server.

**How does this set up look?**

We are now looking at TeamCity for versionControl, testing and CI. We intend to set up a new server. Hopefully to replace 1 and 2 above. I have a few questions...

1. How many servers do we need!?
2. Is TeamCity supposed be be installed on its own server?
3. Does anything need installed on the developer machines?
4. Can my testing server also be my TeamCity server?

Comment: As it stands this question isn't really an appropriate question for StackOverflow as it's looking for opinions whereas we mostly deal in things that have a right or wrong answer. If you can make it more specific and less likely to get opinionated answers then it may be ok to stay though. Alternatively you might want to try one of the other sites on the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 0):

Please find my inline comments prefixed as Vishal:

How many servers do we need!?

Vishal: The server set up is okay, you can install team city on the version control server itself.

Is TeamCity supposed be be installed on its own server?

Vishal: Not necessary.

Does anything need installed on the developer machines?

Vishal: Nothing related to this, but obviously should have SVN for commiting the changes to version control.

Can my testing server also be my TeamCity server?

Vishal: Depends on the configuration of the machine, I would prefer to use the server where SVN is installed as TC server also